# Einsteinpy black hole?

Tags: python, physics

I am a student trying to code a black hole with a star orbiting around it with Einsteinpy. The example code which I have does not show how to add the masses of the two objects I need. All I want to do with this is code a star with a mass of X orbiting a black hole of mass Y at a distance of Z. I need to use this module as it uses Einsetin's correction to Newton's formula.

I checked the user guide and there's nothing on coding something like this.

https://docs.einsteinpy.org/en/latest/user_guide.html

If anyone knows how to use this module or can figure this out I would be grateful.

```
import numpy as np

from einsteinpy.geodesic import Timelike
from einsteinpy.plotting.geodesic import GeodesicPlotter

position = [40, np.pi / 2, 0.]
momentum = [0., 0., 0.]
a = 0.
steps = 5500
delta = 1.

geod = Timelike(
    metric="Schwarzschild",
    metric_params=(a,),
    position=position,
    momentum=momentum,
    steps=steps,
    delta=delta,
    return_cartesian=True
)


gpl = GeodesicPlotter()
gpl.plot2D(geod, coordinates=(1, 2)) # Plot X & Y only
gpl.show()
```